# In Spring MVC, how can RequestMapping be specified to depend on session attribute?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In response to a certain client requests, i would like to write two different methods, but can't seem to be able to do that...
I would like both methods to be mapped to the same request pattern, however the difference between the two methods, is that i would like one  to be called when a certain attribute is in the session, and the other when the attribute is not in the session.

In my first attempt i wrote a single method that handled both cases:

```
@RequestMapping(<some pattern>)
public ModelAndView loadData( @SessionAttribute("data") Data data, 
           @RequestParam("action") String action) {
    if (data == null) {
       Data data = new Data();
       session.setAttribute("data", data);
    }
    //additional processing using data
    return ...
}
```

but, when the request did not have the attribute Data, Spring failed to map it to the above method, and it is documented that it will be that way...

So in my second attempt i created two different methods with the same request mapping, but with different signature:

```
//i want this method to be called when Data in NOT in the session. 
//this methods creates the Data object and sets it into the session
@RequestMapping(<some pattern>)
public ModelAndView loadDataNew( HttpSession session, @RequestParam("action") String action) {
    Data data = new Data();
    session.setAttribute("data", data);
    return loadData(data, action);
}

//i want this method to be called when Data IS in the session. 
//this methods maps that Data object from the session into the parameter Data
@RequestMapping(<some pattern>)
public ModelAndView loadDataContinue( @SessionAttribute("data") Data data, 
           @RequestParam("action") String action) {        
    return loadData(data, action);
}
private ModelAndView loadData( Data data, String action) {        
    //additional processing
    return ...
}
```

But this is problematic to Spring and it complains: "Ambiguous mapping", probably because they both have the same request mapping.

Is this a bug in Spring? I would have expected it to know how to map to the right method, based on the method parameters (since in the first case the Data argument is null which is not allowed, So Spring should know to use the second matching method)...

Is there a way to have Spring map the session to a method parameter but only if it exists? 
I can just have have a single method signature that obtain or sets the Data, as in:

```
@RequestMapping(<some pattern>)
    public ModelAndView loadDataNew( HttpSession session, @RequestParam("action") String action) {
        Data data = session.getAttibute("data");
        if (data == null) {
            data = new Data();
            session.setAttribute("data", data);
        }
        //additional processing using data
        return ...
    }
```

but i was hoping to get a more elegant solution using Spring's mapping...
(i can potentially introduce a new request param, and the mapping would be based on it (or its existence) but that's not very elegant)

Comment: Method arguments aren't taken into account when building the request mapping at startup. So no it isn't a bug this is how spring works. You can specify the `required` attribute in the `@SessionAttribute` which would let you write a single method (and would save you a line of code). If you really want and want to extend the request processing of Spring MVC you can implement your own `RequestCondition` and extend the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` to act upon it. But that is a lot more work then simply create a dispatch method yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: "Is there a way to have Spring map the session to a method parameter but only if it exists?"

after some research based on the hint by M. Deinum it turns out I can use the method i tried in my first attempt as is (as written in the question). The only thing i needed (and that was what i was looking for in an answer) was the "value=" and "required=false" in the annotation of the optional session param:

```
@RequestMapping(<some pattern>)
public ModelAndView loadData( @SessionAttribute(value="data", required=false) Data data, 
           @RequestParam("action") String action) {
    if (data == null) {
       Data data = new Data();
       session.setAttribute("data", data);
    }
    //additional processing using data
    return ...
}
```